# Dropdownlist selected value in asp.net 4.5 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, drop-down-menu, asp.net-4.5

I am using an external JavaScript file which will give me a message when a Dropdown list value is not selected. It is set 'Select' by default. I have tried a lot of things I found while searching, but it is not running on my site. I am using Visual studio 2013 with 4.5 frame work.

Below is the code I have tried.

```
function unicollege()
{

    var ddlObject = document.getElementById("<%=ddlType.ClientID%>"); 
    var selectedValue = ddlObject.options[ddlObject.selectedIndex].value; 

    var e = document.getElementById("ddlLocation");  
    var selectedLocation = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 

    // .option and .value property are not available in my program.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what needs to be in your page to use the external javascript file:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
        this,
        typeof(Page),
        "",
        ResolveClientUrl("JavaScript1.js"));
     }
```

In your aspx markup use a variable for your ddl to reference in your external javascript file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var ddl = "<%=ddlList.ClientID%>";
    </script>
```

and in your external javascript file:

```
    /// <reference path="WebForm1.aspx" />

    function unicollege() {

    var ddlObject = document.getElementById(ddl);
    var selectedValue = ddlObject.options[ddlObject.selectedIndex].value;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried but it is not working. One more thing i would like to tell you. My Java script works if I put it inside asp.net file but when i put it in extenal JavaScript file it does not work. I hope this may help you understanding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you dont really need to think this much complex.
i do these kind of work every day a thousand times.

```
function unicollege()
{
   var ddlSelectedValue = document.getElementById("ddlType").value; 
}
```

this i just sent u after testing..it is going to work perfectly fine and i am doing it for a long time.however be careful about the postback problems if they happen.